# Initial jQuery form validation before using $.ajax() call with data populated using serializeArray()

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to do initial validation before using $.ajax() call (where additional validation is performed) to save on calls to the server. Currently I'm using the following :

```
$('.form_submit').submit(function() {       
        var frm = $(this);
        var url = frm.attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serializeArray();
        var proceed = true;
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            var name = data[index].name;
            if ($('#' + name).hasClass('required') && value == '') {
                $('.label_' + name).append('Please provide the value');
                proceed = false;
            }
        });
        if (proceed) {
            $.ajax({
```

but the value of the 'proceed' variable doesn't seem to be taken under consideration and the validation goes straight to ajax.

Any help would you much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could consider using [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) ?

Comment: You see - this is it - I don't really want to use any plugins - but I've just figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to achieve it and add support for all other fields as well (such as radio buttons, textareas etc.) - here's what I've come up with:

```
$('.form_submit').submit(function() {   
    $('.warn').remove();    
    var frm = $(this);
    var url = frm.attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    var radios = frm.find('input:radio');
    var checks = frm.find('input:checkbox');
    var proceed = true;
    $.each(radios, function(index, value) {
        var elem = frm.find('input[name='+radios[index].name+']');
        if (elem.hasClass('required') && $("input:radio[name="+radios[index].name+"]:checked").length == 0) {
            var val = elem.attr('title');
            if ($('.label_' + radios[index].name).find('.warn').length == 0) {
                $('.label_' + radios[index].name).append('<span class="warn">'+val+'</span>');
            }
            proceed = false;
        }
    });
    $.each(checks, function(index, value) {
        var elem = frm.find('input[name='+checks[index].name+']');
        if (elem.hasClass('required') && $("input[name="+checks[index].name+"]:checked").length == 0) {
            var val = elem.attr('title');
            $('.label_' + checks[index].name).append('<span class="warn">'+val+'</span>');
            proceed = false;
        }
    });
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        var elem = frm.find('[name='+data[index].name+']');
        var elem_type = elem.prop('nodeName');
        if (elem.hasClass('required') && elem.val() === '') {
            var val = elem.attr('title');
            $('.label_' + data[index].name).append('<span class="warn">'+val+'</span>');
            proceed = false;
        }
    });
    if (proceed == true) {
        $.ajax({ // here start server side validation
```

I've assigned the validation message to the 'title' attribute of the 'input' field - so that you can have a different one for each tag. With radio buttons - simply add 'title' to the first button.